# Getting null value when sending xml to web api controller from swagger UI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger-ui

Developing Web API using Asp.net core with swagger. Posting XML to web API from swagger UI but it is giving null at controller side. follows following steps.

Here is the Startup.cs code where XML formatter added:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Adding XML Format Support
    services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

    // Register the Swagger generator, defining one or more Swagger documents
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v2", new Info { Title = "API", Version = "v2" });
        string xmlpath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"SwaggerAPI.xml";
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlpath);
    });
}
```

Here is Controller Code:

```cs
[Route("api/Employee")]
public class RuleController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("add")]      
    [Consumes("application/json", "application/xml")]    
    public void Post([FromBody]Employee employee)
    {

    }       
}

public class Employee  
{  
    public int Id;  
    public string FirstName;  
    public string LastName;  
}
```

From Swagger UI posting xml to web api:

[image: PostingXMltoWebAPI]

Here is the debug window:

[image: DebugWindow]

Please suggest anything I missed here. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like an issue with the casing of the elements you are posting.

Comment: Yup. As @CalC said, the casing of your XML sent in Swagger is off. XML is case sensitive (as per: http://xml.silmaril.ie/case.html) , so `<firstName>` is different to `<FirstName>`

Comment: Thanks @Calc, it works.

Comment: Thanks @Jamie. How can we on the casing of XML?

Answer (score 1):

In the screen shots you have provided, the request casing does not match the casing used in your model.

[XML is case sensitive](http://xml.silmaril.ie/case.html), so you will need to change the casing of your request to match the casing that your POCO (Plain Old C# Object) is expecting.

In your example, you are sending:

```
<?xml version="1.0>
  <Employee>
    <firstName>First</firstName>
    <lastName>Last</lastName>
  </Employee>
</xml>
```

This doesn't match the POCO property names given in your subsequent screen shot. Presumably your POCO will look similar to this:

```
public class Employee
{
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Which means that the XML tag `<firstName>` doesn't map to the POCO property `FirstName` because the XML tag doesn't have a leading upper case `F`.

Changing your XML to the following should parse correctly:

```
<?xml version="1.0>
  <Employee>
    <FirstName>First</FirstName>
    <LastName>Last</LastName>
  </Employee>
</xml>
```

Please note the difference, as it is a subtle but important one:

```
<firstName>First</firstName>
```

vs

```
<FirstName>First</FirstName>
```

Comment: I got above by your first comment. I misread your sentence "casing of your XML sent in Swagger is off." I understand that i suppose to do something in swagger configuration.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I should have made that specific comment simpler. In British English saying that something is off can mean that something about it is not correct. You were doing everything correctly, aside from your XML tags being incorrectly cased.